# Matrix definition from it's components given a formula

Tags: matrix, code-request, elements

I'm pretty new to mathematica and I'm using it to do some "simple" calculations. For one I need to evaluate a matrix which is given by a [review article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/9512380.pdf) (equation III.97 for those who are interested) in the following form

$$H_{ij} = \delta_{ij}\gamma^{(0)}_i\frac{\beta_0}{2\beta_1}-\frac{G_{ij}}{2\beta_0+\gamma^{(0)}_i-\gamma^{(0)}_j}$$

where $\vec{\gamma}^{(0)}$ is a vector, $G_{ij}$ is a matrix and $\beta_{0,1}$ are come coefficients which are all given. The first bit of the expression I can easily implement just by taking the diagonal matrix which has the elements of $\gamma^{(0)}$ on the diagonal. What I don't know is how to implement the second bit since it forces me to define the matrix $H$ only through its elements.

I'm not using any specific code atm and I don't think that the rest, which just defines the coefficients and the matrix $\gamma^{(0)}$, would be of any help. Moreover the code is helplessly horrible, but it does its job.

*Edit*: I forgot tu add that the matrices $H,G$, the $\beta$-coefficients and the $\gamma$ vectors, all depend on $3$ parameters that have to be passed to $H$ like one does for a function.

If more informations are needed I'll gladly add them.

Comment: Why not just define it as a function: `H[i_, j_, G_, β0_, β1_, γ_] := 
 KroneckerDelta[i, j] γ[[i]] β0/(2 β1) - 
  G[[i, j]]/(2 β0 + γ[[i]] - γ[[j]])` then pass in i,j and the rest ? You construct those other things G, β0, β1, γ fully, prior to calling this function of course.

Comment: @flinty What if I then want to treat H as a matrix? Like if I need to do matrix multiplication using the dot command. Because what I need to find in the end is a matrix which comes from H by means of multiplication by some other matrices.

Comment: Make H a function as I've described. Then afterwards you can generate a matrix using `Hmtx = Table[H[i, j, G, β0, β1, γ], {i,1,3},{j,1,3}]` which you can use later with dot etc.

Comment: @flinty I'm going to try this and I'll get back if I have problems, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second term you can use an `Outer[Subtract, ...]` construct:

```
n = 3;
γ0 = Array[α, n];
G = Array[g, {n, n}];

H = DiagonalMatrix[γ0]*β0/(2*β1) - G/(2*β0 + Outer[Subtract, γ0, γ0])
(*    {{-g[1,1]/(2β0) + β0*α[1]/(2β1), -g[1,2]/(2β0 + α[1]-α[2]), -g[1,3]/(2β0 + α[1]-α[3])},
       {-g[2,1]/(2β0 - α[1]+α[2]), -g[2,2]/(2β0) + β0*α[2]/(2β1), -g[2, 3]/(2β0 + α[2]-α[3])},
       {-g[3,1]/(2β0 - α[1]+α[3]), -g[3,2]/(2β0 - α[2]+α[3]), -g[3,3]/(2β0) + β0*α[3]/(2β1)}}    *)
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have worked!